# Why does my Palindrome function keep returning false?

Tags: c++, string, palindrome

I have a text file that consists of:

```
1457887541

Madam

Able was I ere I saw Elba

Straw? No, too stupid a fad. I put soot on warts.

Class is cancelled today
```

and when I run the program, I get all strings returning `false` and can't figure out why that is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(string);

int main()
{
string input;
fstream nameFile;


nameFile.open("Xample.txt", ios::in);


if (nameFile)
{
   cout << "Now reading from file: " << endl;
   // Read an item from the file.
   getline(nameFile, input);

   // While the last read operation 
   // was successful, continue.
   while (nameFile)
   {

  cout << input << endl;
  //Palindrome function call
  if(isPalindrome(input)){
    cout << "It is a Palindrome :)/> " << endl; 
      }
  else {
    cout << "It is not a Palindrome :'( " << endl;
  }

   // Read the next string.
   getline(nameFile, input); 


}
   //Close when completed
   cout << "Done!" << endl;
   nameFile.close();
 }
 else
{
  cout << "ERROR: Cannot open file.\n";
}
return 0;
}



bool isPalindrome(string input){


int first = 0;
int last = input.length() - 1;



//begin loop to compare first position with last
while(last > first){
//loop if it is not a number or letter
while(!isalnum(input[first]) && !isalnum(input[last])){
    first++;
    last--;
    }
if(tolower(input[first]) != tolower(input[last])){
    return false;
    }

last--;
first++;

}


return true;





}
```

Comment: Which anomalies did you observe when stepping through your program line by line with a debugger?

Comment: You havent added  ")" in if statement during function call.

Comment: Oops, I somehow added an extra one, but I have that fixed now. I don't know if it was the online compiler I was using, but my code works fine using putty..

Answer (score 2):

Without running/debugging your code, I think the problem is in your algorithm. This part of your code looks like it's designed to get around the problem of spaces and punctuation.

```
//loop if it is not a number or letter
while(!isalnum(input[first]) && !isalnum(input[last])){
    first++;
    last--;
}
```

That doesn't work though. You're skipping both the current first and last character if both of them are not alphanum characters, but you should only skip one or the other most of the time, so you should separate this out into two if statements instead of one loop.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to edit your code and run it, as Bill was saying the problem is your **logic**.

```
while(!isalnum(input[first]) && !isalnum(input[last])){
  first++;
  last--;
}
```

If input[first] is not alpha numeric you should increment only it and decreasing at the same time *last*.

Here it is the corrected versione of the function, have a look so it will be more clearn

```
bool isPalindrome(string input){
  int first = 0;
  int last = input.length() - 1;

  while(last > first)
  {
    if(!isalnum(input[first]))
        first++; //Increment only first
    else if(!isalnum(input[last]))
        last--; //Decrement only last
    else if(tolower(input[first]) != tolower(input[last])){
        return false;
    } 
    else
    {
        last--;
        first++;    
    }           
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is obviously "because your code doesn't do what you think or want" (not that that's very helpful by itself).

Unless you *really* need to examine the data "in place" it's almost certainly  easier and more understandable to copy the data you care about, then check whether the result is a palindrome:

```
bool is_palindrome(std::string const &input) {
    std::string temp;

    std::copy_if(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(temp), isalnum);
    return temp == std::string(temp.rbegin(), temp.rend());
}
```

If doing the job in-place is important, I'd still try to logically separate the "skip characters we don't care about" part from the "check if the result is palindromic" part. One way to do that would be to build the filtering into a special iterator. For one example, encapsulating the filtering into a Boost `filter_iterator` would still keep the code relatively straightforward and understandable.

Comment: personally I would have reversed the string and then checked it, I did not know about vector::rbegin and vector::rend, yeah my solution would have worked as well but yours it's more elegant and clean. So thanks!